# DB2 Disable auto commit inside stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have several inserts in my stored procedure. But if any block has an error, all made inserts should be reverted. This means all the operations inside the stored procedure should be atomar.
Concretely in my example below, when block 2 failed, than all the inserts from block 1 should be reverted. How can I do it?

```
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;
--Block 1
  PREPARE S1 FROM 
  'WITH TEMP AS 
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLEE 
    WHERE ID = 2
  ), 
  TEMP_1 AS 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS ID 
     FROM NEW TABLE 
      (
        INSERT INTO TABLE_A (Col_1, Col_2)
        SELECT Col_1, ''' || V || '''
        FROM TABLE_A
        JOIN TABLEE ON ID = Col_1
      )
  ),
  SELECT 1
  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1';
  OPEN C1;
  CLOSE C1;

--Block 2
  PREPARE S1 FROM 
  'WITH TEMP AS 
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLEEX 
    WHERE ID = 2
  ), 
  TEMP_1 AS 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS ID 
     FROM NEW TABLE 
      (
        INSERT INTO TABLE_AA (Col_1, Col_2)
        SELECT Col_1, ''' || V || '''
        FROM TABLE_AA
        JOIN TABLEE ON ID = Col_1
      )
  ),
  SELECT 1
  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1';
  OPEN C1;
  CLOSE C1;
```

Comment: by default there is no autocommit inside your stored procedure itself. The caller might have autocommit enabled or might explicitly commit after the CALL succeeds, but that is separate matter.  Inside your stored procedure, declare an exception handler for errors, and in that exception handler, code a rollback, but take care to ensure that the scope of the database transaction is limited to the set of changes inside your stored procedure (i.e. the caller should have committed any previous changes, or the caller has autocommit enabled).

Comment: If you want to rollback whatever was done in SP disregarding of calling application behavior (say, it may still issue `commit` even after SP failure), you should use `EXIT HANDLER` + [savepoint](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-savepoint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEST_SP (I INT) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS@

COMMIT@

INSERT INTO SESSION.TEST_SP (I) VALUES 1@

BEGIN 
--/*
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
  BEGIN 
    --ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT SP1;
  END;
--*/
  --SAVEPOINT SP1 ON ROLLBACK RETAIN CURSORS;
  INSERT INTO SESSION.TEST_SP (I) VALUES 2;
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error!';
END@

COMMIT@

SELECT * FROM SESSION.TEST_SP@
```

If you run this script as is with autocommit switched off, you get 2 rows in the session table. The same is when the exception handler definition is commented out entirely.
But if you uncomment the 2 commented out lines (with `SAVEPOINT`), you get 1 row in this table (inserted by the 1-st standalone `INSERT`) - all the changes made by the `BEGIN END` block will be rolled back by the `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` statement.

Note, that you could achieve the same with an `UNDO` [handler](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-compound-sql-compiled) (see *handler-declaration*), but it's allowed in the inlined compound sql only (`BEGIN ATOMIC ... END`), and you can't use it since you need dynamic sql (`PREPARE`).

Comment: Its working fine, but when using the Exit Handler, how can I propgate the error message throwing out. When I am calling the stored procedure, no error message was shown

Comment: Use the [RESIGNAL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-resignal) statement (without any parameters) as the last statement of the handler definition, if you want to make the routine to return the original error code and message.